# in VBA multiple delimiter use separate one row data to another two row

Tags: excel, vba

hi im trying to use multiple delimiter to separate one sell data to another two cell.

Please refer

[image]

as image shown raw data are store in A1,A2 up to A100. now using VBA should I used multiple delimiter for split data in 2 column as like C and D where D hold items quantity?

my code is

```
Sub SplitColumnData()

Dim LastPopulatedRow As Long, MyString As String
Dim StringPart() As String, ColIndex As Long
Dim MinArrSubscript As Integer, MaxArrSubscript As Integer

 
Dim LastPopulatedRow1 As Long
Dim StringPart1() As String
LastPopulatedRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("i2").Value = LastPopulatedRow


'Loop through each populated cell in column A
 For RowIndex = 1 To LastPopulatedRow

'Split the cell value, here single space is the delimiter
 StringPart() = Split(Range("A" & RowIndex).Value, "-")

 MinArrSubscript = LBound(StringPart)
 MaxArrSubscript = UBound(StringPart)

 'Range("i2").Value = MaxArrSubscript

'Store each split string columns
 'For ColumnNum = MinArrSubscript To MaxArrSubscript
 'Cells(RowIndex, 2 + ColumnNum).Value = StringPart(ColumnNum)
 'Next ColumnNum
 
 LastPopulatedRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
 
 'Store each split string row
 For rownum = MinArrSubscript To MaxArrSubscript
 
  Cells(LastPopulatedRow1 + rownum, 6).Value = StringPart(rownum)
 'Cells(LastPopulatedRow1 + rownum, 7).Value = StringPart(rownum)
 
 
 Next rownum
 Next RowIndex



 
 End Sub
```

problem is i can not place data as like given way..

please refer image test3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the Array directly into the Worksheet without using a loop, like this:

```
Dim ArraySize As Long, OutputRange As Range

ArraySize = 1 + MaxArrSubscript - MinArrSubscript
Set OutputRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastPopulatedRow1, 6).Resize(ArraySize, 1)

OutputRange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(StringPart)
```